# How can I test that a function was called inside an if statement in jasmine-karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

I'm creating an Angular app and I'm learning unit test and I want to test certain method, but I can't manage to test that the function enters in the if statement. I don't know how to force it. Could you please teach me how to do that? This is the function:

```
currentRoute(): void {
    const router: Router = this.injector.get(Router);
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
             this.checkMenuLinks(val);
        }
    });
}
```

If I run a test-coverage I get al the if statement in red, as not tested. Could you please tell me how to achieve this? Thank you so much.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the testing tool you're using, and more to do with the scenarios you're causing to happen in your tests.

You should ask yourself why you wrote the code inside the if statement - what case does it solve?

Though code coverage is about code, testing should be about behaviour.

Comment: That's a common testing scenario in Angular, and by default the routing doesn't occur without some additional effort (added some details below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're not triggering router events in your unit test - which is quite normal

You should look up the Angular `RouterTestingModule`

- https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule

There's some good tutorials on testing the routes themselves, and you'll be looking to trigger the Navigation End event, which should occur during the process. You can add a `jasmine spy` to the `checkMenuLinks()` method to check if it's been called

- https://dev.to/this-is-angular/testing-angular-routing-components-with-the-routertestingmodule-4cj0

Other approaches involved mocking the `Router` service, and often this is the most efficient approach